# Publish a Nuxt 3 app/components on npm that is usable by normal Vue 3 without Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3, npm-publish

The usual way for me publishing a vue component is based on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QV9wVc8c7g). And for Nuxt 3, the workflow is way easier, almost nothing much to configure just `npm publish` and then just install the package, use extend, and it's just work.

So my question is, how to configure a Nuxt 3 app that can cater for both Nuxt3 and Vue project(without Nuxt). So does it mean I still need to use index.js, then configure my nuxt.config

```
nuxt.config

vite:{
  build: {
    lib: {
      // Could also be a dictionary or array of multiple entry points
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
      name: 'MyLib',
      // the proper extensions will be added
      fileName: 'my-lib',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
      // into your library
      external: ['vue'],
      output: {
        // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
        // for externalized deps
        globals: {
          vue: 'Vue',
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

I also have configuration for gh-pages

```
nuxt.config

  app: {
    baseURL: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "/my-repo-name/" : "/",
    buildAssetsDir: "assets",
  },
```

how do I make a config that use different build if I want to run them separately

What I have currently

for my gh-pages

```
package.json

    "deploy": "nuxt generate && gh-pages --dotfiles -d .output/public"
```

and build for npm

```
package.json

    "npmx": "nuxt build .npm-publish",
```

The result produced by nuxt build is something I'm not familiar with to the normal vite build that I had before. It does look like usual nuxt build output. So how do I solve this? Any suggestion or links I can look up for? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So to use the files like components and layout, we can just publish the corresponding folders to npm. So it will be just Vue files when we import.
**The package.json of the nuxt project**

{
"name": "@harikrishnan_pv/test-buttons",
"version": "1.0.6",
"description": "A collection of reusable Nuxt 3 components",
"files": [
"components",// to include components folder
"layouts" // to include layouts folder 
],
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
"build": "nuxt build",
"dev": "nuxt dev",
"generate": "nuxt generate",
"preview": "nuxt preview",
"postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
},
"keywords": [
"nuxt3",
"components",
"reusable"
],
"author": "harikrishnan p v",
"license": "MIT",
"devDependencies": {
"@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
"@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.10.1",
"nuxt": "^3.8.2",
"vue": "^3.3.8",
"vue-router": "^4.2.5"
}
}

so in npm it will be vue pages. 
[The published npm package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1vPE.png)

**Install it in nuxt or vue project and import where ever you want**

```
import blue from '@harikrishnan_pv/test-buttons/components/Button/blue.vue';
```

> replace "blue" with your component name and the "@harikrishnan_pv/test-buttons/components/Button/blue.vue" with your path

**for example you can try mine :- npm i @harikrishnan_pv/test-buttons**